# What is a non-trivial upper bound on the $k$th prime below a given prime $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a prime number $p_0$, by Bertrand's postulate we know that
\begin{gather}
p_1\ge\frac{p_0}{2}\\
p_2\ge\frac{p_1}{2}\ge\frac{p_0}{2^2}\\
\vdots\\
p_k\ge\frac{p_0}{2^k}
\end{gather}
where $p_1,p_2,\dots$ are prime numbers immediately preceding $p_0$.

> **Question.** Is there a similar nice upper bound for the $p_i$?

A trivial upper bound would be $p_i\le p_0-2i$, but that is trivial and bad in the sense that for large $i$ this doesn't give a good approximation (since one or two primes may differ by $2$, but $10$ consecutive primes can't all differ by $2$, there must be something better). I am not claiming that the above result due to Bertrand gives a good approximation, but that at least gives exponential bounds, unlike in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no good upper bound for $p_k$ in the following sense: for every $k$, there exists a constant $c_k>0$ such that $p_k>p_0-c_k$ holds for infinitely many primes $p_0$. This was proved by [Maynard (2013)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4600). You will find a concrete value for $c_k$ in Maynard's work, which was decreased by [Polymath8b (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897). The best conjectured value would follow from the [Hardy-Littlewood prime tuple conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple).

Note also that the crude lower bound $p_k>p_0/2^k$ can be improved greatly. For example, Baker-Harman-Pintz (2000) proved that, for $x$ sufficiently large, there is always a prime in the interval $[x-x^{21/40},x]$. In particular, we have $p_1>p_0-p_0^{21/40}$ for all but finitely many primes $p_0$. This is still far from being optimal. The Riemann Hypothesis implies that the exponent can be replaced by any number exceeding $1/2$. Further, a [conjecture of Cramér](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture) states that $x^{21/40}$ can be replaced by $2(\log x)^2$.

Comment: Is the best (known or expected) upper bound of the form $p_k \leq p_1 -c k \log k$ for some explicit constant $c$?

Comment: @WillSawin: Maynard (2013) gave $k^3e^{4k}$ for the constant, Polymath (2014) gave $ke^{(4-24/181)k}$. Assuming the prime $k$-tuple conjecture, one can take $(1+o(1))k\log k$ for the constant.

Comment: Sure, but those are upper bounds, and the original question was about lower bounds. The lower bound for the size of an admissible $k$-tuple is something like $(1/2+ o(1) ) k \log k$, which also gives an (unconditional) lower bound for gaps.

Comment: @WillSawin: I see your question now. It is clear that $p_k\leq p_1-h_k+k$, where $h_k$ is the smallest diameter of an admissible $k$-tuple, and even that $p_k\leq p_1-h_k$ when $p_1$ is large. The prime $k$-tuple conjecture implies that the last bound is sharp. Now the large sieve gives $h_k\geq(1/2+o(1))k\log k$, and a simple construction yields $h_k\leq(1+o(1))k\log k$. The upper bound is conjectured to be the actual size of $h_k$.